# how to disable "WHERE" condition on php

Tags: java, php, sql

I have `WHERE` clause in my PHP. I need that condition, but sometimes I don't need it, here's my code:

```
(SELECT * FROM jasa WHERE kota = '$kota' order by id desc LIMIT :hal,7)
```

I need to know how to disable that clause. Sometimes I need a special condition from my data but sometimes I need to take all the data, or is there any command to take all data with `WHERE` clause?

My best solution is use if command on my android apps, but it will take a long time and code.

Comment: would you please describe your condition in your question?

Comment: This is very basic SQL. Did you even search or try yourself? The first search result I get with "select all records sql" is this > http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the "where condition" out from the query and make the condition separately and add with the query .

```
if(condition to use where condition)
    $where = "WHERE kota = '$kota'";
else
    $where = "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM jasa ".$where." order by id desc LIMIT :hal,7";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way

```
$str = '';
if($kota){  // condition yours, right now it's $kota should be there
$str = "WHERE kota = '$kota' order by id desc LIMIT :hal,7"; // as you need all data if condition is false
} 
$query = "SELECT * FROM jasa ".$str ;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: consider editing your answer to make it properly formatted, plus to elaborate what was the issue, answering the main question, not just providing rough code snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One dirty trick is to have a "dummy" condition in addition to the real one:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     jasa 
WHERE    1 = :dummy OR kota = :kota 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT    :hal, 7
```

If you need the condition you bind dummy=0 and the value for `kota`, and if you don't you bind dummy=1 and something (probably `null` for readability) for `kota`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = '';
if ($kota) {
    $where = sprinft("WHERE kota = '%s'", $kota);
}

$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM jasa %s ORDER BY id DESC', $where);
```

You'll want to sanitize the value of $kota as well to prevent SQL injections.